# Server 2012 R2 - "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection"

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines

I have a VM running Windows Server 2012 R2. I can access content hosted on the server fine, and I can access intranet stuff in the same domain, but I am unable to reach the internet. I have tried everything from resetting IE to restarting the server with no luck. It was working fine until I resetted IE in an attempt to solve a different problem.

When I troubleshoot the issue, it tells me "The remote device or resource won't accept the connection." To my knowledge, nothing has been affected except for my initial reset of IE. Does anyone know what could be causing this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, resetting IE removed my proxy settings. Restoring those fixed everything.